# How to capture mouse click outside of a panel

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

How can I capture a mouse click outside of a panel in an Windows Form application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question, set the panel's Capture property to true.  All mouse input events are now directed to the panel, even if the mouse is outside of the panel window.  This is however a temporary conditions (as it should be), a button click is going to cancel the capture after the click is delivered to the panel.  The MouseCaptureChanged event lets you know when that happened.  Unconditionally capturing the mouse is not an option, typing Ctrl+Esc for example will always cancel it.

Answer (score 3):

To capture global mouse and keyboard events you need to capture the windows messages WM_MOUSE_LL and WM_KEYBOARD_LL,  not just WM_MOUSE and WM_KEYBOARD.   These events can only be captured in NT/2000/XP.  In later OS versions this is not possible (for fairly obvious security reasons I assume).

If you are using NT/2000/XP here is some example code:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx) event of the form itself.

```
class YourForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);

        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution won´t work when the user clicks on a different control than the form or the panel, and I think that in the question what it is asked is to detect all clicks done outside the panel